# String of file_get_html can't be edited?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

Consider this simple piece of code, working normally using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, it outputs **current community**.

```
<?php

    //PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser from simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    //Target URL
    $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';

    //Getting content of $url
    $doo = file_get_html($url);

    //Passing the variable $doo to $abd
    $abd = $doo ;

    //Trying to find the word "current community"
    echo $abd->find('a', 0)->innertext; //Output: current community. 

?>
```

Consider this other piece of code, same as above but I add an empty space to the parsed html content (in the future, I need to edit this string, so I just added a space here to simplify things).

```
<?php

    //PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser from simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    //Target URL
    $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask';

    //Getting content of $url
    $doo = file_get_html($url);

    //Passing the variable $url to $doo - and adding an empty space.
    $abd = $doo . " ";

    //Trying to find the word "current community"
    echo $abd->find('a', 0)->innertext; //Outputs: nothing.     
?>
```

The second code gives this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function file_get_html() in /home/name/public_html/code.php on line 5
```

Why can't I edit the string gotten from file_get_html? I need to edit it for many important reasons (like removing some scripts before processing the html content of the page). I also do not understand why is it giving the error that file_get_html() could not be found (It's clear we're importing the correct parser from the first code).

**Additional note:**

I have tried all those variations:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
include('simple_html_dom.php');
require('simple_html_dom.php');
```

Comment: There should be *an* error, but not *that* error. This makes no sense, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_html()` returns an object, not a string. Attempting to concatenate a string to an object will call the object's `_toString()` method if it exists, and the operation returns a string. Strings do not have a `find()` method.

If you want to do as you have described read the file contents and concatenate the extra string first:

```
$content = file_get_contents('someFile.html');
$content .= "someString";
$domObject  = str_get_html($content);
```

Alternatively, read the file with `file_get_html()` and manipulate it with the DOM API.

Comment: Thank you so much for the piece of code you have written. Worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

`$doo` is *not a string*! It's an *object*, an instance of Simple HTML DOM. You can't call `->` methods on strings, only on objects. You cannot treat this object like a string. Trying to concatenate something to it makes no sense. `$abd` in your code is the result of an object concatenated with a string; this either results in a string or an error, depending in the details of the object. What it certainly does not do is result in a usable object, so you certainly can't do `$abd->find()`.

If you want to modify the content of the page, do it using the DOM API which the object gives you.

Comment: The code 1  is working perfectly. So $abd is an object?

Comment: Strictly, in code 1, `$abd` is a copy of a _reference_ to `$doo`. Both `$abd` and `$doo` refer to the __same__ object